# Data migration Mongo + Mongoose / sequelize + postgres

Tags: javascript, mongodb, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to migrate data from MongoDB to Postgres. Already have models and other stuff. Using ORM Sequelize.

I'm new with this and want know how to make data migration when i have `.json/.bson` formats (dump from mongo)